# How to retrieve JSON data in controller in ASP.net Core?

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc

i need to get data sent with JSON and save to model in asp.net controller

```
  //JSON data
        var dataType = 'application/json';
        var data = {
            ID: 'Zaki',                
        }

        console.log('Submitting form...');
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Save',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: dataType,
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('Data received: ');
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save([FromBody] string ID)
    {
       
        return Json (ID);


    }
```

am getting null in console , it supposed to be zaki and from there i wanna write saving code...

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get data from you DB and wanted to bind with Model to display on your console? It is bit unclear with your question.

Comment: no am trying to get data from JSON and save it to DB

Comment: If i am not wrong, your json should look like this.  var data = {"ID": "Zaki", }

Comment: i added a screenshot , i think the problem is not in sending is getting data

Comment: Then Create a Model for  your Json and use JsonConvert to Serialize like this : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewlyCreatedJsonModel))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify this line in your code **data: data,** to

**data:JSON.stringify(data)**

When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string and JSON.stringify method converts a JavaScript object into a string.

Another approach would be, instead of getting raw string value, wrap your parameter into a class object like this

```
public class ParamObj
{
public string ID{get;set;}
}
```

and in your controller get a parameter of this object type like this..

```
public ActionResult Save([FromBody] ParamObj data)
```

Thanx

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to simply use 'dynamic' type to handle json request data. Take a look:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult YoutMethod([FromBody] dynamic requestData)
{
  Log.Information(requestData.field1);
  Log.Information(requestData.field2);
  // ...

  return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that is already marked as answered, but here is another way to do it:

I am not using the binding FromBody attribute.

Controller

```
    public class JsonRequest
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(JsonRequest data)
    {

        return Json(data.Id);
    }
```

Instead of using **dataType** I am using **accept** and you don't need to convert your json into a string.

To avoid problems with relative paths I am using:  url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")' as well.

Javascript

```
function send()
{
    //JSON data
    var dataType = 'application/json';
    var data = {
        "id": "Zaki"
    }

    console.log('Submitting form...');
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")',                        
        accept: dataType,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Data received: ');
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Good luck with your project.